# Are there non-stress-related homographs in Russian?

Tags: ударение, омографы

Are there homographs in Russian that sound different [besides the stress](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/4232/homographs-that-differ-only-with-respect-to-a-stress)?

E.g. like "read" in English:

```
I will read (ee) that book
```

VS

```
I have just read (e) that book
```

P.S. I hope the answer to this question won't be just "NO" :-)

Comment: Seems to be duplicate of https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-heteronyms-aka-heterophones

Comment: But that question was closed for unclear reason. In the comments there was one more couple of words, besides of already mentioned here: пОлого (genitive of полый (hollow)) - полОго (adverb meaning "not steeply").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One example that I know is "считать". When it means "count" or "consider", it's pronounced with single "щ" in the beginning; but when it is perfective aspect of the verb "считывать" (to read off?), it's pronounced with separate sounds "s" and "ʧ".

Comment: I pronounce the second one with double "щ", yet still you've got the point! +1

Comment: Yet some people may pronounce the separate sounds in the first meaning too, for example an aunt of my mother always pronounced ч as ч and I think it is a variant of norm.

Answer (score 12):

**Конечно** is normally pronounced with [ш] for **ч** to mean 'of course' and with [ч] to mean 'finite': множество конечно, 'the set is finite'.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you will hardly find homographs that differ *only* by stress. Stress position [may affect pronunciation](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/191/pronunciation-rules-for-%D0%BE-in-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%CC%81%D1%82%D1%8C) of all vowels in a word. So I will answer a question whether there are homographs with the stress on the same syllable.

There are a lot of loaned words where letter *е* stands for non-iotated sound /ɛ/ and this case isn’t reflected in spelling in any way. And I can recall at least one word which can be misunderstood by this reason. *Те́ста* may be read /'tɛstə/ (gen. of *тест* — test) or /'tʲestə/ (gen. of *тесто* — dough, pastry). The same applies to instr. *те́стом*, dat. *те́сту* and prep. / loc. *в те́сте*.

Comment: Yet one can pronousce the word for test with soft t so the words become indistinguishable.

Comment: "you will hardly find homographs that differ only by stress" - there's hundreds if not thousands of them: зАмок/замОк, пОлосы/полосЫ, вЫносим/вынОсим/выносИм.

Comment: @SergeySlepov, is’s strange to hear this from a native Russian speaker. *За́мок* in (Moscow) Russian is /'zamək/, while *замо́к* is /zɐ'mok/, *по́лосы* is /'poləsɨ/, *полосы́* — /pəlɐ'sɨ/.

Comment: You are using non-phonemic transcription in your comment. In Russian transcription system they are written the same.

Answer (score 3):

Some words can become omographs if we omit dots above ё letter.
This happens oftenly in modern internet communications.

Examples: мёл / мел; сёл / сел; осёл / осел; берёт / берет; etc.

Other than that I don't know any omographs besides the stress.

Comment: Non only in modern communications - letter ё is used mostly in educational literature, dictionaries etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Метр** can be read as [mʲetr] 'metre' or [mɛtr] to mean 'master', [maître](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ma%C3%AEtre#French).

Around the 1990s, they [changed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80#%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80_III) the spelling for 'master' to **мэтр** to avoid the ambiguity, while **метрдотель** is still spelled with a soft **e**.

Answer (score 0):

Another example I can come with is the word **бог** "god". In the sense of Christian God it can be pronounced with either plosive or fricative g, but in the sense of a polytheistic religion, like Ancient Greek one, it is always pronounced with plosive g.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept proper nouns, then there is **того** (genitive of тот, with г pronounced [v]) and **Того** (Togo, the country).

Comment: They have different stress.

Comment: По́лого [-в-] — поло́го [-г-]. They do have different stress but the difference in not stress related.