# считывать, считать (heteronyms, AKA heterophones)

Tags: произношение, местоимения

In the Russian language we pronounce the written word `считать` differently,  `с-читать` или `щщитать`, depending on what is expressed. (they are heteronyms, also known as heterophones, for English it's here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteronym_(linguistics) ).

If we desribe in Russian the picture:

```
An electromagnetic head reading data from a magnetic tape.
Электромагнитая головка считывает данные с магнитной ленты.
```

we pronounce `с-читать` with 2 short sounds. One more example:

```
The head can read out data from a magnetic tape.
Данная головка может считать данные с магнитной ленты.
```

When the picture is

```
one thinks about something, that … ; he takes into account something    
cчитается, что … ; он считает, [e.g.: надо + глагол]
```

then we use the pronunciation `щщитать` with a single long sound:

```
Я считаю, что мы достигли своей цели. 
Он может считать, что достиг цели. 
Он считает, надо достигнуть цели.
```

There is plenty of examples for the latter, sitting right in the google searching output https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%8F+%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%22 , usually written in twitter-dritter-style or joke-style grammar (sounding utter illiterate otherwise).

**__Addition__:**
For those who doubt in pronunciation of the heterophone `считать` as `с-читать` there is a search query: [https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=считыватель](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)

<s>Any other heteronyms / heterophones in Russian?</s>
The 5 others most frequently used heteronyms / heterophones in Russian?

Comment: usually asking about a list of words is not something that can be answered in a single answer. For me this sounds to broad, I'm voting to close this. If the community will found this worth to re-open, than so let it be.

Comment: In Russian such words are called `омографы` https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%8B. Here is a list of words, which are written equally, but are pronounced with different stress and have different meaning: http://accentonline.ru/homograph.html. But other kinds of different pronunciation, like in `считать`, are much rarer. I didn't find any other examples yet.

Comment: Found one example: `конечно`. If it means "of course, certainly", then `ч` is pronounced like `ш`. But if it means "finitely" (adverb or short adjective from `конечный` ("finite")), then `ч` is pronounced as written.

Comment: I can think of one more example. It may be considered somewhat artificial because the stress moves as well, but nevertheless:  

"Слово или выражение, подвергнутое нарóчному искажению носителем языка, владеющим литературной нормой..." — "ШН".  

"Нáрочному было велено нигде на задерживаться" — "ЧН".

(Feel free to up-vote any of my answers elsewhere. When I am at 3000 I will be able to re-open closed questions without having to refer to moderators :) )

Comment: While there's really a difference in pronunciation of конечно/конечный, I find it unnatural to pronounce separately c+ч, at least in the word считывать. The meaning of this word even doesn't depend on pronunciation. Is thе с+ч idea mentioned in any work? So far I've found this: https://how-to-all.com/фонетика:считывать

Comment: @Lara thank you, this is the answer. `Данное множество конечно / Я согласен, конечно` will have its pronunciation `конеч-но / конешно`. @AviGordon : yes, that's it, to some degree, thank you.

Comment: @Alex_ander, what city/town are you from? I noticed that people from some regions (namely St.Petersburg and maybe some other ones) have this specific variant of pronunciation. For example, pronounce `дождь` as `"дощщь"`, and so on. I can expect to hear `"щщитывать"` from people with this kind of pronunciation, but not from others. I don't really know, which pronunciation is considered correct, but never even thought about it, because everyone (or almost everyone?) I used to talk to pronounces it with separate `с` and `ч`.

Comment: @Lara I am from St. Petersburg (where my parents were born as well). I only pronounce дошть и дожди, while I always considered дощщ and дожжи typical for old Moscow dialect - at least I only hear that version from Central TV announcers, Pugachova the singer, etc. I don't duplicate щ at pronunciation in cases other than -ссч-. Also noticed Moscow announcers tended to 'duplicate' single letter -н- (юнный, длинна, etc.).

Comment: So I am highly skeptical about standards of pronunciation and even didn't join the discussion here: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429297/Как-правильно-произносить-пятьдесят since where I live, the correct version is "пидисят" :)

Comment: I have one more example: `полого` as an adverb or as an adjective, where it's pronounced as `"полого"` or `"полово"`, respectively. Compare: `Поляна полого спускалась к лесу` vs  `внутри полого цилиндра`.

Comment: @zipirovich, nice example! Found one more: words `тест` ("test") and `тесто` ("dough") are written identically in all cases except for nominative and accusative (`ошибка в тесте` -- `сосиска в тесте`, etc.). But pronunciation is different: in the first one `т` is not palatalized, and `e` sounds like `э`, while the second one is pronounced as written.

Comment: @Lara: Yes, I know! Why didn't I post it myself? Когда после 14 дет жизни в Штатах мы приехали в отпуск в Москву, я постоянно заказывал (для детей) `сосиску в тэсте`. Детям было смешно. :-)

Comment: @Alex_ander, maybe the difference is actually between old and new pronunciation, not between regions? And double `н` instead of single looks quite new to me, I hear it mostly from young people, and on the internet even sometimes see it in written form.

Comment: @shabunc, is there really a rule that questions that require a list of answers should be closed as "too broad"? I've found only this question on Meta: http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/questions/347/what-to-do-with-questions-that-require-a-list-of-answers, with only one answer that suggests to transform such question into community-wiki QA (I don't understand what it is, however). This question looks good and interesting to me, I don't see real reasons to close it.